# Laravel :: The requested resource /hello was not found on this server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I got error when I change .php file to .blade.php.
Before I changed it got this error.

```
Route::get('hello','HelloController@index');
```

**HelloController**

```
public function index()
    {
      $data = array(
    'name'  => 'Rakesh',
    'email' => 'sharmarakesh395@gmail.com');
      return View::make('hello.index')->with('data', $data);
    }
```

**/public/hello/index.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Laravel 5.3 - Home page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Welcome Hello index </h1>
      <h1>{!!$data!!}</h1>
      <h1>{!!$data['email']!!}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Error**

```
The requested resource /hello was not found on this server.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The view should be inside `resources/views` folder instead of `public` folder

Comment: Thanks a lot it's my fault.I see video in youtube and follow him.

Answer (score 38):

That error occurs when you create a folder in the public folder with the same name as your route so please change the name of the folder you have put in the public folder so that it has a different name from your route this will probably solve your error

Comment: You saved my life! I've never thought about that

Comment: after 4-5 hrs of changes finally this was the problem.

Comment: This I wouldn't know

Comment: Yes - fixed it! This was one of those things which is not in a "textbook" .